# Moderation in cloglog regression

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interaction, panel-data

I am testing the effect of climate on task completion and am thinking about including two variables as moderators in my cloglog regression.

I am wondering if it makes sense to enter these moderators in the analysis. And if so, how would I do it in R? Would I simple create interaction effects?

Comment: Whether it makes sense to include the moderators in the model is hard to judge as you don't provide any detail on what these moderators are of what your estimation framework looks like. If you provide those details you can probably get an answer to your question. In general for moderators it is useful to include them as interaction effects since the effect of the explanatory variable on the outcome variable depends on the moderator variable.

Comment: @horseoftheyear would they be added as interaction with the IV or DV? what differentitaes them from control variables? and does it make sense to enter them in this kind of analysis? thank you!

Comment: The outcome variable is only for the left-hand side of the equation; otherwise it is endogenous. Say $y$ is your outcome, $x$ some variable of interest, and $z$ other factors you want to adjust for, e.g. your moderators. Then your estimation framework will be $y_{it} = \alpha + \beta x_{it} + \theta z_{it} + \gamma (x_{it}z_{it}) + \epsilon_{it}$. Note that $\gamma$ is the interaction effect. Whether it makes sense to include it really depends on the underlying theory or whatever hypothesis your testing.